# laravel 5.1 Route - Object not found!

Tags: php, framework, laravel

Помоги пожалуйста с роутом!
Вот такой роут работает

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'aa';
});
```

А вот такой не хочет и выдает ошибку "Object not found!":

```
Route::get('about', function () {
    return 'aaa';
});
```

Уже несколько часов в пустую, столько всего перепробовал, может кто подскажет!

Использую xampp последней версии:
httpd.vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost test.loc:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/apps/test.loc/public"
   ServerName test.loc
   <Directory "C:/xampp/apps/test.loc/public">
            #AllowOverride All - так вообще не работает пишет "Access forbidden!" для всех роутов
        Require all granted - так главный роут работает а другие нет.
</Directory>
```

/public/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в настройках Laravel ничего не меняли то должно работать, ещё попробуйте вот так:

```
Route::get('about/', function () {
return 'aaa';
});
```

и 
   `Route::get('about/bar', function () {
    return 'aaa';
});`

и попробуй перейти по обоим ссылкам. Посмотрим что будет

Comment: вообщем поставил заново laravel все равно пишет object not found

Comment: Так а скажите версию php и apache??? и пробовали ли Вы код который я Вам привёл в действие?? И где вы вообще прописываете роутинг??